# force maven to fail the build on nonnull violations

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I have the simple code below for testing the findbugs NonNull annotation with maven.

I execute "mvn clean install site",
and I get a directory target/site/css and target/site/images,
but nothing more.
I was expecting to get a report, saying that println(null) violates the NonNull condition.

What do I need to do to get that report?

Also,
is there a way to prevent "mvn clean install" to succeed if there are NonNull violations?

---

Note: I am aware that I can get such report with Sonar;
However, I would like "mvn clean install" to fail if there are such errors,
without the need to use an optional Sonar tool afterwards.

---

src/main/java/test/Hello.java

```
package test;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull;
public class Hello {
    static public void print(@NonNull Object value) {
        System.out.println("value: " + value.toString());
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            print(args[0]);
        } else {
            print(null);
        }
    }
}
```

and the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

### ---

**Update, Solution**

solution, based on the answer from Augusto:
Add this to the pom.xml file, under project:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includeTests>true</includeTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>findbugs-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

With this, "mvn clean install" will fail if there is a NonNull violation.

The reporting was not working for me, because I am using maven 3,
and the reporting feature has changed in maven 3 (now it uses a normal maven plugin)

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you read the manual entry where it explains how to do it? http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html ?

Comment: thanks Augusto, that solved the question; please add an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I just added the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Good question and answer, but the solution finds much more bugs than just the annotation issues.  How do I limit FindBugs to only care about the annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David,

The answer to your question is in the [findbugs maven plugin documentation](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/) (see findbugs:check)

Comment: You should give the main idea, not just the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - see Provide context for links

Comment: findbugs is not supported anymore, they propose to used [spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) instead