# How do I configure the FindBugs maven plugin to only check for annotation violations like @Nonnull?

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I've implemented the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291713/force-maven-to-fail-the-build-on-nonnull-violations) to make it so @Nonnull violations make the build fail.  But the problem is, this is finding lots and lots of other bugs that I don't want to deal with yet.  I've looked at [the manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html), and there's no section that jumps out at me as a, "Here's how you configure what to check for" chapter.

To me it seems like [it should be in here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/analysisprops.html), but the number of options don't seem nearly comprehensive enough.  How would I configure findbugs to **only** care about the findbugs annotations?

I'll probably accept an answer that tells me how to do it without using the maven plugin because I think I can figure out how to translate that into something the plugin can use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the findbugs maven configuration I use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The findbugs-exclude.xml file is in my project root directory (same level as pom.xml - I should probably put it somewhere better), and it configures what findbugs issues I want to ignore.  Here's what's in my exclude file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP,EI_EXPOSE_REP2"/>
    </Match>
    <Match>
        <Package name="com.mypackage.something"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

There's more info about configuring the findbugs filter files [in the findbugs manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)

Also nore that you could change the findbugs maven plugin to only include certain filters using this instead of `excludeFilterFile`:

```
<includeFilterFile>findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
```

Comment: OK I found that part of the documentation but it made me believe that the filter was for filtering out files as opposed to bugs to check.  The first sentence says, "Filter files may be used to include or exclude bug reports for particular classes and methods".  Very misleading.  That's why I passed through this chapter.

Comment: @tieTYT yes, I remember that confusing me when I first read the docs too.  Thankfully it's more powerful than that - hopefully you can configure it for your needs.

Comment: note, we like the files solution because then you can also configure eclipse to use the same files.

Comment: This does not seem to work, at least for me. I've had the suspicion that the xml file its'nt actually used (also same folder as pom.xml), so I added some invalid code to the exclude xml file and no error message of any kind appears. How would I specify the file location of the exclude file resp. what's the default location?