# Spring @Nullable check for maven compiler

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way (except with the IDE) to check the @Nullable Annotation of Spring with the maven compiler plugin?
I know with the codechecker framework there is the NullnessChecker for maven. Since we already have Spring(boot) in classpath I would prefer this variant. Does anyone know of an opportunity for Spring @Nullable checker?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [force maven to fail the build on nonnull violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291713/force-maven-to-fail-the-build-on-nonnull-violations)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use the maven compiler plugin for this, because we are talking about annotations here, that would be solved most of the time with Aspects.

I think the solution you are searching for is [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: No this is no runtime feature. It's a compiler feature see springframework.guru/what-is-new-with-spring-framework-5 But currenlty i just found a solution to get warnings for intellij but not with maven

Comment: Please also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484202/how-to-use-nullable-and-nonnull-annotations-more-effectively

Comment: You also could use tools like CheckStyle, PMD and SpotBugs to improve your code quality.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291713/force-maven-to-fail-the-build-on-nonnull-violations

Comment: Thanks for this posts, but I have already read this articles.

Iam asking how the spring developer handle this, because this feature is new for spring 5. And we develop with spring boot, so we would like to use the spring annotation, because they already in our classpath

Comment: They added the annotations to the framework, so that the ide's and other tools can use them the verify the calls to spring methods etc.

Comment: That's the question just for the IDE or which other tools.


And if there are ways test code can not be checked.

Comment: As already said, please have a look at SpotBugs, PMD and CheckStyle.